# css - multi line line-clamp (ellipsis) doesn't work

Tags: ellipsis, linefeed

[problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCH5H.png)

I applied this class to h3 tag.

```
.ellipsis-2 {
  $lines: 2;
  $line-multiple: 1.3;
  $font-size: 1em;
  display: block;
  display: -webkit-box;
  max-height: $font-size * $line-multiple * $lines;
  line-height: $font-size * $line-multiple;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  -webkit-line-clamp: $lines;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

As you saw in image, there is full lines of text and ellipsis didn't show.

But when I resize screen, ellipsis works fine.

Problem occured only the first time page rendering.

Any adivce?

Answer (score 24):

This is my solution to this:

HTML

```
<mat-expansion-panel>
  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
    {{ stuff here }}
  </mat-expansion-panel-header>
  <div class="mat-expansion-panel-content">
    <div class="mat-expansion-panel-body">
      {{ stuff here }}
    </div>
  </div>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

CSS

```
.mat-expansion-panel-body {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Set visibility property of the panel content's child to *visible*.

So, you can avoid the wrong rendering on the first load.
I was hitting my head against the wall for two days in order to solve this.
I hope it can save someone some time.

Comment: Boom, that was easier than I expected. Thank you!

Comment: Should be ```visibility: visible;``` (you got typo in the word "visibility").

Comment: Thanks, @ErnestasRomeika! ;)

Answer (score 15):

Almost an year old post, still answering as this might help someone.

This could happen if the element with `-webkit-line-clamp` has it's visibility set to hidden when it first renders, either directly or by inheriting from one of its parent. This is due to this webkit bug: [-webkit-line-clamp is not respected when visibility is hidden](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=45399).

As a workaround, instead of visibility, you can set `display: none` if possible.

Comment: this answer is more accurate even if both are correct. Brilliant.

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me with Angular in July 2022 on Chrome and Safari, when this block size is constrained by parent with flex-basis:

```
.your-class {
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    /* autoprefixer: ignore next */
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    display: -webkit-box;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-break: break-word;
}
```

Thanks to [@Leonardo Rick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10526869/leonardo-rick)

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is with a framework such as Angular that runs a autoprefixer on styles, maybe this solution will work for you:
https://medium.com/@gawadnikita/angular-6-issue-of-line-clamp-css-not-working-a6b591bda9bf

```
overflow: hidden;`
text-overflow: ellipsis;
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-line-clamp: 3;
/* autoprefixer: ignore next */
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
```

Add a `/* autoprefixer: ignore next */` exactly before `-webkit-box-orient: vertical;` and this should work