# text-overflow: ellipsis; not working with mat-expansion-panel

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I'd like to apply `text-overflow: ellipsis;` to the [mat-panel-description](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/api#MatExpansionPanelDescription) of a [mat-expansion-panel](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview):

```
.mat-expansion-panel-header-description {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 100%;
}
```

While the overflow is hidden, there are no ellipsis. See the following screenshot of [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gsxyhn?embed=1&file=app/expansion-overview-example.css&view=preview):

[image]

Wrapping is intentionally prevented since I don't want the description to wrap onto a second line. The long URL is also intentional:

```
<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel>

    <mat-expansion-panel-header>

      <mat-panel-title>
        Panel Title
      </mat-panel-title>

      <mat-panel-description>
      https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gsxyhn?file=app%2Fexpans ion-overview-example.html
      </mat-panel-description>

    </mat-expansion-panel-header>

  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

Comment: It seems to work if you set `display: inline-block;` on the element (see [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gsxyhn-armozj)).

Comment: You should post the rendered markup and the css a couple of levels up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you will come to find out that if you just put text in flex containers you can run into problems. I think it is best if you have a container element to hold your text and will help you in this case.

Once the content is placed in some container, [there is one thing that needs to be done to get the ellipsis to show up](https://css-tricks.com/flexbox-truncated-text/)... add `min-width: 0;` to the `mat-expansion-panel-header-description` class.

```html
<span class="mat-content">
    <mat-panel-title class="mat-expansion-panel-header-title">
        <div>Panel Title</div>
    </mat-panel-title>
    <mat-panel-description class="mat-expansion-panel-header-description">
        <div>https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gsxyhn?file=app%2Fexpans ion-overview-example.html</div>
    </mat-panel-description>
</span>
```

```css
.mat-expansion-panel-header-title {
    flex: 0 0 auto; /* make this not grow or shrink */
    margin-right: 16px;
}

.mat-expansion-panel-header-description {
    flex: 1 1 auto; /* make this grow and shrink */
    min-width: 0; /* see link to see why this is needed */
    margin-right: 16px;
}

.mat-expansion-panel-header-description > div {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: Wow this worked great thank you. I merged everything into the expansion-panel-title and it worked perfect for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it changing the child's visibility property.
Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53268674/5124373).

Ellipsis won't work on a *visibility: hidden* element, or any of its children inheriting this property.