# How to display 2 lines with ellipsis at the end with css in react js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

I want to display post description in 2 lines with ellipsis at the end . I actually copied the styles needed from inspecting youtube css styles . Youtube styles work on all browsers like safari and iOS devices browsers .

[image]

[image]

and I use inline styling in react js like this :

```
                       <span
                          style={{
                            lineHeight: "2rem",
                            fontWeight: "500",
                            maxHeight: "4rem",
                            overflow: "hidden",
                            display: "-webkit-box",
                            textOverflow: "ellipsis",
                            whiteSpace: "normal",
                            WebkitLineClamp: 2,
                            WebkitBoxOrient: "vertical",
                            msTextOverflow: "ellipsis",
                          }}
                        >
                          {description}
                        </span>
```

The problem is it doesn't on macbook safari browser or any iOS device browser but it is the same css styles that youtube has .

How can I make sure that these styles work on iOS devices browsers and safari ? Is there something missing ?

Comment: Can you share your current result?

Comment: I have no iOS devices nor do I use React, but I created a mini-tutorial comparing *ellipsis* with *line-clamp* last June on **[CodePen: Scaled variable text/line-clamp ellipsis comparison](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/JjpeaZX)**. This is supposed to work on iOS. Lemme know...

Comment: @AloisoJunior https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73268136/how-to-show-ellipsis-at-the-end-of-a-text-with-ios-safari   I've mentioned the problem here it's about direction rtl and text ellipsis on the left side in safari and iOS devices

Comment: @AloisoJunior https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73268136/how-to-show-ellipsis-at-the-end-of-a-text-with-ios-safari   I've mentioned the problem here it's about direction rtl and text ellipsis on the left side in safari and iOS devices

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the below solution, it works fine..

on my component.js file

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import classes from "./component.module.css"

export const Component = () => {
   return (
    <div className={classes.css}>
        I want to display post description in 2 lines with ellipsis at the end. I actually copied the styles needed from inspecting youtube css styles .
    </div>
   )
```

on my component.module.css file

```
.css{
    width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
}
```

[Output with expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1C239.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73268136/how-to-show-ellipsis-at-the-end-of-a-text-with-ios-safari   I've mentioned the problem here it's about direction rtl and text ellipsis on the left side in safari and iOS devices

Answer (score 1):

this problem for postcss plugin use `/* autoprefixer: ignore next */` before  `-webkit-line-clamp: 2;`

```
/* autoprefixer: ignore next */
-webkit-line-clamp: 2;
```

[css - multi line line-clamp (ellipsis) doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38989475/css-multi-line-line-clamp-ellipsis-doesnt-work)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73268136/how-to-show-ellipsis-at-the-end-of-a-text-with-ios-safari   I've mentioned the problem here it's about direction rtl and text ellipsis on the left side in safari and iOS devices

Answer (score 1):

```css
.lines {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: -webkit-box;
    box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    padding :0 2rem
    }
```

```html
<div class='lines'>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
```

Comment: How can I implement line-clamp with ```text-align:right``` and ```direction:rtl``` ?

Comment: Add two lines 

 text-align:right;
    direction: rtl;

Comment: If it is not clear, I will explain with an example

Comment: I know that but then the ellipsis disappears on iOS safari

Comment: You can check through this website if the attributes are supported on your device or not == https://caniuse.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
style={{
  overflow: 'hidden',
  textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
  display: '-webkit-box',
  WebkitLineClamp: 2,
  WebkitBoxOrient: 'vertical'
}}
```

This pretty much worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).