# How to show ellipsis at the end of a text with iOS safari?

Tags: javascript, css, ios, safari, webkit

I'm trying to show ellipsis at the end of the text If the text is over 2 lines like this :

[image: safari]

```
/* Text ellipsis */
.two-line {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
}
```

```
<div class="two-line">
In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content. Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is available.
</div>
```

It works perfectly fine in both iOS safari and other browsers . The only problem I have is when I add `text-align: right` or `direction: rtl` it completely hides the ellipsis in safari browser :

[image: safari hides the ellipsis]

```
/* Text ellipsis */
.two-line {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  text-align: right;
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```
<div class="two-line">
In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content. Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is available.
</div>
```

How can I show text ellipsis when it's direction is rtl with iOS safari ?